# Custom element is not supported

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I am using [mewebstudio/Purifier](https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier) in my Laravel project.

I have a custom vue-component `<image-slides>` which can be created by the user, and a want to store it into  database, so

**user input example:**

```
<h2>My Title</h2><image-slides images="https://i.imgur.com/123.jpg,https://i.imgur.com/321.jpg"></image-slides><p>some text</p>
```

when using default `Purifier` config:

```php
clean('<h2>My Title</h2><image-slides images="https://i.imgur.com/123.jpg,https://i.imgur.com/321.jpg"></image-slides><p>some text</p>');

=> "<h2>My Title</h2><p>some text</p>"
```

I add the `<image-slides>` to the **config/purifier.php**

```php
return [
    'encoding'           => 'UTF-8',
    'finalize'           => true,
    'ignoreNonStrings'   => false,
    'cachePath'          => storage_path('app/purifier'),
    'cacheFileMode'      => 0755,
    'settings'      => [
        'default' => [
            'HTML.Doctype' => 'XHTML 1.0 Transitional',
            
            // before
            'HTML.Allowed' => 'div,b,strong,i,em,a[href|title],ul,ol,ol[start],li,p[style],br,span[style],img[width|height|alt|src],*[style|class],pre,hr,code,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,blockquote,del,table,thead,tbody,tr,th,td',
            
            // after
            'HTML.Allowed' => 'div,b,strong,i,em,a[href|title],ul,ol,ol[start],li,p[style],br,span[style],img[width|height|alt|src],*[style|class],pre,hr,code,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,blockquote,del,table,thead,tbody,tr,th,td,image-slides[images]',
        ...
```

But I got error:
**Element 'image-slides' is not supported (for information on implementing this, see the support forums)**

---

I already clean the cache for both laravel and purifier([remove /storage/app/purifier folder](https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier/pull/82#issuecomment-366526644))

How can I add a custom tag for Purifier?

Answer (score 0):

just define it in `config/purifier.php`

```
return [
    'settings' => [
        'default' => [
            'HTML.Allowed' => 'image-slide[images]'
        ],
        'custom_elements' => [
            ['image-slides', 'Block', 'Flow', 'Common', [
                'images' => 'Text'
            ]]
        ]
    ]
];
```